# Pointer notation vs array notation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I like pointer notation in C more than I like array notation, but just can't figure it out for some cases. I have the following code, and the body of `main`

```
/*converts arguemnt to number using atoi()*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i, times;

    if(argc < 2 || (times=atoi(argv[1])) < 1) {
        printf("Usage :%s positive-number\n", argv[0]);
    } else {
        for(i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            puts("Hello");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How would I express `argv[1]` and `argv[0]` in pointer notation?

Comment: Do you mean pointer arithmetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to point out a fun fact:

If you have and array (`int arr[5]`) or a pointer all of the following are equivalent:

```
*(arr + i);
*(i + arr);
arr[i];
i[arr]; // This last one is rather interesting now isn't it.
```

Comment: That's neat, I never would have thought of the last one actually working

Answer (score 6):

`argv[i]` is equivalent to `*(argv + i)`

I really can't imagine why you would prefer the latter over the former.

Answer (score 0):

```
p[n]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
*(p + n)
```

Comment: Boom, thank you. I'll accept once the time runs out.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean pointer arithmetic then `argv[1]` would be

```
*(argv + 1)
```

but I would go with `argv[1]`.